# Using ScottPlot in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, scottplot

I'm quite new with WPF and data binding. I am creating a bar chart using ScottPlot in WPF User Control. After studying the ScottPlot website I am still unable to bind my chart to the code behind.
I imported the ScottPlot chart into my UC and named it chartWPF. Now I have some code behind customizing the chart data.
How can I connect these two together?

This is what i have as the code behind:

```
public UReport()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var plt = new ScottPlot.Plot(600, 400);
                    
        double[] values = { 26, 20, 23, 7, 16 };
        double[] positions = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        string[] labels = { "PHP", "JS", "C++", "GO", "VB" };
        plt.AddBar(values, positions);
        plt.XTicks(positions, labels);
        plt.SetAxisLimits(yMin: 0);
        plt.SaveFig("bar_labels.png");

     
    }
```

and this is in my UC XAML:

```
<ScottPlot:WpfPlot x:Name="chartWpf"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't add a bar chart to the WpfPlot, it creates an uninteractive plot and adds the bar chart to that. You can access the plot object of the WpfPlot with `chartWpf.Plot`, so your code becomes something like this:

```
public UReport() { 
    InitializeComponent();                    
    double[] values = { 26, 20, 23, 7, 16 };
    double[] positions = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    string[] labels = { "PHP", "JS", "C++", "GO", "VB" };

    chartWpf.Plot.AddBar(values, positions);
    chartWpf.Plot.XTicks(positions, labels);
    chartWpf.Plot.SetAxisLimits(yMin: 0);
    chartWpf.Plot.SaveFig("bar_labels.png");     
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Ben! That definitely worked